# digital clock [top bar] font error after disabling unnecessary fonts!

Tags: fonts, gui

How do I get the clock font back to normal from this?

[image: instead of colon, there is a white square]

It would be helpful if I could know the font that is used there.

Comment: Apparently you disabled some font which was not unnecessary then.

Comment: found it; it was freesan & other freefonts.

Comment: @n1lotpal Nice that you solved your problem! Can you also add an answer with the fonts you installed and how you installed them? You can then mark your own answer as the solution. This way other users with an issue similar to yours may be helped! Thanks! :)

Comment: @BeastOfCaerbannog how do you mark a reply as solution in stackexchange?

Comment: @n1lotpal You need to post an answer first. Then you click on the gray checkmark right next to it. Note, however, that since you are answering your own question, you have to wait for 48 hours after posting the answer before being able to accept it.